# Azure Function Error: The operation has timed out

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

An error has started popping up in my Azure Data Factory Pipeline. I have a few Azure Function steps in the pipeline, but for some reason, one of the Azure Function steps has started returning an error. In Azure Data Factory, the error is a 3608 code after running for 1 minute 40 seconds:

Failure type: User configuration issue
Details: Call to provided Azure function 'CollateSheetsHTTPTrigger' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'.

However, in a prior run sub-pipeline, this Azure Function ran successfully on the same data (parameters and worksheet are on the only difference). The subsequent 3 runs of pipelines fail immediately (after 2 seconds) at the first Azure Function (a different AZ function now) step in each, with the same 3608 error code but different details:

```
Call to provided Azure function '???????????????' failed with status-'NotFound' 
and message - '<html> <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head> <body 
bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx</center> 
</body> </html> '.
```

Now it gets even stranger. After these 3 failed pipelines, the next pipeline which is pretty much the same as the previous 4 except for a few parameters, runs successfully, even though it has the same 2 AZ functions that failed before. And then the next 2 pretty similar pipelines also run successfully.

I then went and looked at the monitoring page for the 2 Azure Functions:
The first AZ function that failed, had 2 errors even though it only failed once in AZ Data Factory... the timing is slightly different for the 2 errors but they could only come from the first failed pipeline, so why does it say there are 2 errors? Then if you look at the actual error, all it says is "The operation timed out". The function was not running for more than 150 seconds so this is strange. Additionally, I have a bunch of error catching code and nothing comes up there.

The other failed AZ function steps from the other function do not show up on the monitoring page, it seems as if the first error crashed the AZ function app and then it eventually restarted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Azure Support Engineer identified the issue, it was due to a change to the azure-function-host library. The relevant issue is here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6936 and was fixed last week

Comment: Weird url? It redirects to https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6936

Comment: Thanks, I must have copied the URL directly from my Outlook email which first goes to Mimecast to check that its safe. Edited to fix

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I can't help but I did have a similar problem with an Azure function that executes a SOAP-call to a webservice every minute. Since 4 days this also fails with a timeout. If I run the function within my debugger it runs without problems. But the Azure Function fails every time, after 20 sec.

I'll follow this question and hope someone else can help...